# Iterating over two lists of text elements (or a list of pairs)

Tags: comma-separated-list, paracol

Let's assume I have two lists of text elements - `L1,L2,L3,...,Ln` and `R1,R2,R3,...Rn` - or a list of pairs - `(L1,R1),(L2,R2),(L3,R3),...,(Ln,Rn)`. I want to iterate over them in order to produce an `itemize` list within a 2-column `paracol` environment, like this:

```
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item L1
    \switchcolumn
    \item R1

    \switchcolumn*

    \item L2
    \switchcolumn
    \item R2

    \switchcolumn*

    \item L3
    \switchcolumn
    \item R3

    \switchcolumn*

    ...

    \switchcolumn*
    
    \item Ln
    \switchcolumn
    \item Rn
  \end{itemize}
\end{paracol}
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a plain LaTeX solution. Add the following lines to your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\dopairs[1]{\@for\@tmp:={#1}\do{\expandafter\dopair\@tmp}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\dopair[2]{\item #1\switchcolumn\item #2\switchcolumn*}
```

The command `\dopair` is responsible for typesetting a pair, where `#1` corresponds to the left item and `#2` to the right one. `\dopairs` takes a single argument, a comma separated list of left-right pairs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\dopairs[1]{\@for\@tmp:={#1}\do{\expandafter\dopair\@tmp}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\dopair[2]{\item #1\switchcolumn\item #2\switchcolumn*}
\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \begin{itemize}
    \dopairs{
      {$L_1$}{$R_1$},
      {$L_2$}{$R_2$},
      {$L_3$}{$R_3$},
      {$L_4$}{$R_4$},
      {$L_5$}{$R_5$}
    }
  \end{itemize}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** There are several ways to keep the processing of pairs flexibel.

- Redefine `\dopair` before calling `\dopairs`.

  ```
  \renewcommand\dopair[2]{...}
  \dopairs{...}
  ```
- Prepare all the ways that pairs can be processed, and `\let` the macro `\dopair` to the required definition before calling `\dopairs`.

  ```
  \newcommand\dopairA[2]{...}
  \newcommand\dopairB[2]{...}
  \newcommand\dopairC[2]{...}
  ...
  \let\dopair\dopairB
  \dopairs{...}
  ```
- Prepare all the ways that pairs can be processed as separate macros, and hand the name of the macro over to `\dopairs` as another argument. In this case you have to redefine `\dopairs` as follows.

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \newcommand\dopairs[2]{\@for\@tmp:={#2}\do{\expandafter#1\@tmp}}
  \makeatother
  \newcommand\dopairA[2]{...}
  \newcommand\dopairB[2]{...}
  \newcommand\dopairC[2]{...}
  ...
  \dopairs\dopairA{{}{},{}{},...}
  ```
- Specify the processing of pairs *ad hoc* when calling `\dopairs`. Redefine `\dopairs` as follows.

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \newcommand\dopairs[2]{%
    \def\dopair[2]{#1}%
    \@for\@tmp:={#2}\do{\expandafter\dopair\@tmp}%
  }
  \makeatother
  ```

  For the example, `\dopairs` has to be used as follows:

  ```
  \dopairs{\item #1\switchcolumn\item #2\switchcolumn*}%
  {{}{},{}{},{}{},...}
  ```

  Here is the complete code of the example, giving the same output as shown above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\dopairs[2]{%
  \def\dopair[2]{#1}%
  \@for\@tmp:={#2}\do{\expandafter\dopair\@tmp}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \begin{itemize}
    \dopairs{\item #1\switchcolumn\item #2\switchcolumn*}%
    {
      {$L_1$}{$R_1$},
      {$L_2$}{$R_2$},
      {$L_3$}{$R_3$},
      {$L_4$}{$R_4$},
      {$L_5$}{$R_5$}
    }
  \end{itemize}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In @gemot example, `\dopair` is hardcoded in the definition of `\dopairs`. How could I improve `\dopairs` definition so that I can be able to pass my mandler macro name (in place of `\dopair`) as a parameter?

Comment: @LaérciodeSousa See my extended answer.